# Interacting with contracts that are not instantiated in the blockchain

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I have a question about how EVM and Solidity work. In this example on the official Solidity website, there are two contracts ( Caller, C ). What happens and I didn't know is that I can host the "Caller" contract and still interact with the "C" contract even though it's not instantiated in the blockchain. Just so I understand, does "Caller" host under the hood the "C" contract with you? Because I'm imagining that if I wanted to create a contract that offered several services I would do it just like that, it's much better than passing instance of related contracts in the blockchain. Or is there something I don't understand?

The source code is in ( Getter Functions - https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/contracts.html )

```
contract C {
    uint public data = 42;
}

contract Caller {
    C c = new C();
    function f() public view returns (uint) {
        return c.data();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *does "Caller" host under the hood the "C" contract with you?*

The `Caller` bytecode only contains the definition of the `C`. But not its instance.

---

```
C c = new C();
```

This snippet deploys the defined `C` contract to a new address. Meaning, it copies the `C` definition to a new address and executes the constructor (if applicable).

In the `c` property it stores

- the newly deployed address
- information that it implements the `C` interface

Caller does **not** store the whole instance of the `C` contract in the `c` property. When `Caller` executes a function on the `c` address, the EVM sends an internal transaction (between your `Caller` address and `c` address), and `Caller` only receives the result of the transaction - whether it was successful (or reverted) and the returned binary data. Your `Caller` than typecasts this returned data to typed properties based on the `C` definition that it has on its own address (The `C` definition in the `Caller` contract).

---

If you make the property `public`, you can easily verify that it has been deployed on a new address:

```
C public c = new C();
```

[image: Remix screenshot]

Note that the `Caller` deployed address, and the `c` value are different.

Comment: You totally right! In fact, when I went to sleep, what you explained came to mind. I didn't expose the address but if I did, I would see that there is no way to persist information that is not allocated in the blockchain. My confusion, sorry! Thanks for your comment, I really appreciate it! Thanks and see you!